# T-SQL query for creating an empty parquet file with only header in serverless synapse

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, serverless, azure-synapse

I am trying to come up with a T-SQL query to generate an empty parquet file(with only header info) in serverless synapse.

Currently, if the input file has data in the parquet files (say inputFile1), and on executing a T-SQL query using it and the query returns no values, an empty underscore file (of 0 bytes) is getting created.

Instead of empty file of 0kb, I need an empty parquet file, so the downstream processes don't break. Unable to generate empty parquet file.
Also trying that instead of empty parquet file, or generate a file with some header.
This is so that the downstream process does not break (specific to some scenario tying to work on)

For that, I've tried few T-SQL queries, such as :

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo') DROP EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[MyTableName]; DECLARE @row_count INT CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[MyTableName] WITH ( LOCATION = 'InputLocation', DATA_SOURCE = Some_Source, FILE_FORMAT = [ParquetFormat] ) AS SELECT TOP 0 CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Id; SELECT @row_count = @@ROWCOUNT; SELECT @row_count;

This is creating empty file which is an underscore.("_") instead of an empty parquet file. Any ideas how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

In a serverless SQL pool, you can use queries on Azure Data Lake data in Parquet, Delta Lake, and delimited text formats.

As you mentioned, you need to create an empty Parquet file instead of an empty file, so the downstream processes don't break.

The steps below will help you create a Parquet file in ADLS:

1. Create a Data Factory Pipeline with a copy activity.
2. Set up the Copy activity Sink to be an ADLS2 folder in Parquet format.

Once you have the Parquet file in the Storage account, you can create an external table in Synapse serverless pool.

[image]
Right-click on the file.
[image]

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_file_formats WHERE name = 'SynapseParquetFormat') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseParquetFormat] 
    WITH ( FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources WHERE name = 'folder02_synpstgacc_dfs_core_windows_net') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [folder02_synpstgacc_dfs_core_windows_net] 
    WITH (
        LOCATION = 'abfss://folder02@synpstgacc.dfs.core.windows.net' 
    )
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.tbl_empty (
    [column1] nvarchar(4000),
    [column2] nvarchar(4000)
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = 'empty_parquet_file/part-00000-tid-8452994219104257737-54fcfcb5-23d3-4c7d-acc7-d445fbb41294-0-1.c000.snappy.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = [folder02_synpstgacc_dfs_core_windows_net],
    FILE_FORMAT = [SynapseParquetFormat]
    )
GO
```

**Results:**

[image]